# Power BI - using Switch to calculate subtotals in an income statement

Tags: powerbi, switch-statement, dax, row, powerbi-desktop

I have a fixed format table and am trying to use the switch formula to calculate different rows together. I have allocated a 1,2,3 to a particular row with 1 - sum base data, 2 - sum total administrative expense, 3 - running total.

```
Financial Value = 
  var SelectedCalcType = SELECTEDVALUE('Management accounts structure'[calctype])
  RETURN SWITCH(SelectedCalcType, 
    1,[Total Amount],
    2,[Total administrative expenses],
    3,[total Amount Running Total],
    BLANK()
)
```

[Total Amount] is:

```
Total Amount = SUM('Glentry query'[Debit/Credit Amount])
```

[Total administrative expenses]

```
Total administrative expenses = [Staff related costs]+[Other administrative costs]
```

[Staff related costs] is

```
Staff related costs = CALCULATE([Total Amount],'Account mapping query'[ManagementHeader]="Staff related costs")
```

and [Other administrative costs] is the same but with Other administrative costs as the filter.

Now this works for everything but 2 as this is a subtotal of the 2 previous rows above it so in a way sits outside of 3. Does anyone have any ideas as to how to show subtotals in power bi?

[image]

This is the management accounts structure:

[image: This is the management accounts structure:]

This is my data relationships:

[image: data relationships]

Updated data relationships:
[image: Updated data relationships]

and what the matrix table currently looks like:
[image: what the matrix table currently looks like]

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code for `[Total Amount]` and `[Total administrative expenses]`.

Comment: Can you share what `Management accounts structure` look like. If you update your `SWITCH` to `2, 112233,` what do you see? Trying to understand if the `SWITCH` is not finding `2` or if `[Total administrative expenses]` is not working.

Comment: hi sam, I've added the management structure picture. Interestingly when I change the calctype to 112233, the "Other administrative costs" line still works but the "Total administrative expenses" still doesn't work. Looks to be an issue with the [Total administrative expenses] measure. How can I fix this measure?

Comment: Hard to understand how you have this set-up. Possible to share a PBIX (upload to OneDrive, Google Drive, Drop Box etc... and share the link) - feel free to replace sensitive data with mock data.

Comment: ah unfortunately not, it has too many links to our ERP system and I'm not 100% I can share this file

Comment: Help me understand how when `SelectedCalcType = 1` the `SWITCH` uses `[Total Amount]` and that this returns a different value for `Revenue` and `Staff related costs`.

Comment: its looking at the corresponding rows in the matrix which is based off the management accounts structures

Comment: So there is a relationship between `'Glentry query'` and `'Management accounts structure'` tables? Could you update the question with screen grab of your data model of only the relevant tables for this question, so we can see tables names and relationships.

Comment: yes there is a relationship. Screenshot added to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your data model, you will need to remove the `Management accounts structure` context from the calculation so that `Account mapping query` isn't filtered.

See if this helps:

```
Total administrative expenses = 
  CALCULATE(
    [Staff related costs] + [Other administrative costs],
    REMOVEFILTERS('Management accounts structure')
  )
```

Should `Other administrative costs` be `calctype` 1 or 2? In your annotated screen grab you have it as 1, and in the second it is showing 2. I suspect it should be 1.

---

**Supplimental**
As discussed in the comments, you could alternatively remove the relationship between `Management accounts structure` and `Account mapping query` and do the required filtering in the Financial Value measure for each row calculation.

Your `Financial Value` measure could look similar to:

```
Financial Value = 
  var selectedCalcType = SELECTEDVALUE('Management accounts structure'[calctype])
  var selectedLineItem = SELECTEDVALUE('Management accounts structure'[Line Item ID])

  RETURN SWITCH(selectedCalcType, 

    // 1 = we'll use the line item for filtering where previously the relationship was used
    1,
      [Total Amount]('Account mapping query'[ManagementHeader] = selectedLineItem),
    
    2, 
      var src = [Total Amount]('Account mapping query'[ManagementHeader] = "Staff related costs")
      var oac = [Total Amount]('Account mapping query'[ManagementHeader] = "Other administrative costs")
      return src + oac,

    // update this parts as needed
    3,
      [total Amount Running Total]

  ) // end Switch
```

Comment: Thanks Sam that seems to have worked although I don't fully understand why.  

Why would I need to remove the Management accounts structure from the Total administrative expenses Measure when it isn't being used in the underlying Staff related costs or the Other administrative costs Measures? 

Yes sorry,  Other administrative costs should be calctype 1. I changed it to 2 as you requested earlier to test it. I have now changed it back and its working.

Comment: `Management accounts structure` is used in your visual, this is filtering `Account mapping query` via the relationship, so in this context, `CALCULATE([Total Amount],'Account mapping query'[ManagementHeader]="Staff related costs")` won't work or `"Staff related costs"` is filtered out.

Comment: ah ok I think I understand now. So if I were to add any further management account structure rows in (similiar to the [Total administrative expenses] which could be a sum of some other Measures) I would have to use the removefilters as part of the code ?

Comment: Yes correct - or you could remove the relationship between `Management accounts structure` and `Account mapping query` and do the required filtering in the `Financial Value` measure for each row calculation.

Comment: you mean add the removefilter line to the Financial Value code? 

Which one would be better to use?

Comment: Just keep it as it is above 

Comment: brilliant thanks for taking the time to answer my question Sam, really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi Sam, I've been thinking about this over the weekend. How would I put the code in the Financial Value Measure? my reasoning being we have several management account structures that I may use, so might be better to remove the relationship between the Management accounts structure and Account mapping query so allow me have several Management account structure tables added to the model.

Comment: See the supplemental section at the bottom of the updated answer above. Hopefully this  will give you an idea.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you, the real-world happened the last few weeks. Just picking this up again. So I've updated my code with your supplement (thank you for providing), but now I seem to have lost my totals which I had before.

So original code:
Financial Value 2 = 
VAR SelectedCalcType = SELECTEDVALUE('Management accounts structure'[calctype])
RETURN 
SWITCH(SelectedCalcType, 
    1,[Total Amount], 
    2,[Total administrative expenses], 
    3,[total Amount Running Total], 
    BLANK()
)

Comment: then your supplement code:
Financial Value 2 = 
var selectedCalcType = SELECTEDVALUE('Management accounts structure'[calctype])
  var selectedLineItem = SELECTEDVALUE('Management accounts structure'[Level 1 ID])
  RETURN SWITCH(selectedCalcType, 
    // 1 = we'll use the line item for filtering where previously the relationship was used
    1,
      [Total Amount]('Account mapping query'[Level 1 ID] = selectedLineItem),
    2, 
      var src = [Total Amount]('Account mapping query'[Level 1 ID] = "Staff related costs")

Comment: var oac = [Total Amount]('Account mapping query'[Level 1 ID] = "Other administrative costs")
      return src + oac,

    // update this parts as needed
    3,
      [total Amount Running Total]

  ) // end Switch

Comment: sorry, haven't figured out how to properly post that bit of code in a comment!

Comment: The supplement code depends on their **not** being a relationship between `Management accounts structure` and `Account mapping query`. Have you removed this relationship (or at least deactivate)?

Comment: yep, see screenshot above. Updated data relationships. And what I see from the matrix table. You can see that all the totals are the same.